# dt.time.between returns an empty column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
slots = pd.DataFrame({'times': ['2020-02-01 18:40:00', '2020-02-01 08:40:00',
                                '2020-02-01 03:40:00', '2020-02-01 14:40:00',
                                '2010-05-05 22:00:00', '2018-03-08 23:00:00']})
print(slots)
slots['times'] = pd.to_datetime(slots.times)

from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.strptime('17:09:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
print(start)
end = datetime.strptime('01:59:00', '%H:%M:%S').time()
print(end)


print(slots[slots['times'].dt.time.between(start, end)])


output: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [times]
Index: []
```

I am getting empty dataframe. Can someone please guide or is there any other way to do it.

Comment: Hi @Sam32, You should add more details, what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I think this question is very clear and very interesting, there is no reason to close here.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has method [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) so I suggest use it, also is added [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) because method working with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df = (slots.set_index('times', drop=False)
           .between_time('17:09:00', '01:59:00')
           .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
                times
0 2020-02-01 18:40:00
1 2010-05-05 22:00:00
2 2018-03-08 23:00:00
```